# Preventing fake account creation in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

We have recently totally rewritten our ASP.NET 2.0 Web Forms website and it is now an MVC 4.0 website.  We are experiencing problems with fake accounts being created.  When I look in my IIS log the IP addresses mostly originate from China.  Our ASP.NET 2.0 Web Forms website never experienced any fake accounts being created, so I am wondering if I've done anything wrong to suddenly get so many of these.  Below is a cut down version of our account registration page to illustrate what I am doing...

**Controller**

```
<RequireHttps()>
Function Register() As ActionResult

    Dim ad As New AccountDetails

    Return View("AccountDetails", ad)

End Function

<RequireHttps()>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
Function Register(model As AccountDetails) As ActionResult

    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FormValue1) OrElse Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.FormValue2) Then
            ' Add Code here to display an error
        Else
            Dim SerialNo As Integer = AccountDetailsRepository.InsertRecord(model)

            If SerialNo > 0 Then
                Dim Roles As String = "Standard"

                FormsAuthentication.Initialize()
                Dim fat As FormsAuthenticationTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.FirstName + " " + model.Surname, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes), False, Roles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath)
                Response.Cookies.Add(New HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(fat)))

                Return RedirectToAction("Account")
            Else
                ' Add code here to display an account error
            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return View("AccountDetails", model)

End Function
```

**View**

```
@ModelType User.AccountDetails

<div class="Account">
    <h1 class="PageTitle">Register</h1>

    <div class="AccountDetails">
        <p class="PageHeader">Please enter your account details</p>

        @Using Html.BeginForm()
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "Please correct the following errors:-", New With {.id = "AccountDetailsValidationSummary", .class = "TopValidationSummary"})

            @<div class="AccountDetailsContainer">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.FormValue1, New With {.id = "FormValue1"})
                @Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.FormValue2, New With {.id = "FormValue2"})
                <fieldset id="NameGroup" class="FieldGroup">
                    <legend>Name</legend>

                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label for="FirstName" class="FieldLabel">First Name</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.FirstName, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "FirstName", .MaxLength = 25})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.FirstName)
                    </div>
                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label for="Surname" class="FieldLabel">Surname</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Surname, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "Surname", .MaxLength = 25})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Surname)
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset id="AddressGroup" class="FieldGroup">
                    <legend>Address</legend>

                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label for="Address1" class="FieldLabel">Address 1</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Address1, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "Address1", .MaxLength = 50})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Address1)
                    </div>
                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label for="Address2" class="FieldLabel">Address 2</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Address2, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "Address2", .MaxLength = 50})
                    </div>
                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label for="Address3" class="FieldLabel">City</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.City, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "Address3", .MaxLength = 35})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.City)
                    </div>
                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label for="Address4" class="FieldLabel DropDown">State</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.State, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "Address4", .MaxLength = 4})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.State)
                    </div>
                    <div id="PostcodeContainer" @(If(Not Model.International, Html.Raw("style=""display: block;"""), Html.Raw("style=""display: none;""")))>
                        <label for="PostCode" class="FieldLabel">Zip Code</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.PostCode, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "PostCode", .MaxLength = 15})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.PostCode)
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset id="ContactDetailsGroup" class="FieldGroup">
                    <legend>Contact Details</legend>

                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label for="Email" class="FieldLabel">E-mail</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Email, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "Email", .MaxLength = 100})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Email)
                    </div>
                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label for="ConfirmEmail" class="FieldLabel">Confirm E-mail</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.ConfirmEmail, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "ConfirmEmail", .MaxLength = 100})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ConfirmEmail)
                    </div>
                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label for="TelNo1" class="FieldLabel">Tel No</label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.TelNo1, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "TelNo1", .MaxLength = 25})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.TelNo1)
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset id="PasswordGroup" class="FieldGroup">
                    <legend>Password</legend>

                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label class="FieldLabel" for="WebPassword">Password</label>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(Function(model) model.WebPassword, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "WebPassword", .MaxLength = 25})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.WebPassword)
                    </div>
                    <div class="FieldRow">
                        <label class="FieldLabel" for="ConfirmWebPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(Function(model) model.ConfirmWebPassword, New With {.autocomplete = "off", .class = "Field", .id = "ConfirmWebPassword", .MaxLength = 25})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.ConfirmWebPassword)
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            @<div class="ButtonBar">
                <input type="submit" name="SubmitValue" class="SubmitButton" value="Create Account" id="AccountDetailsSaveDetailsButton" />
            </div>
        End Using
    </div>
</div>
```

My Layout view contains scripts for jQuery and I use unobtrusive validation on client-side as well.

As seen above I've tried a few things:-
1. Adding the AntiForgeryToken.
2. Adding a textbox called FormValue1 which I hide with CSS.
3. Adding a hidden field called FormValue2.

FormValue1 and FormValue2 I check to see if they've been filled in.  As a user should not be able to see these, if they've been filled in I assume it is some sort of automatic hack and don't register the account.

I can consider things like reCAPTCHA but I just wanted to try and figure out if I am doing something wrong, especially as this problem only seems to have started with our MVC 4.0 website and didn't experience this issue with ASP.NET 2.0 Web Forms.

Anything I can do to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it has anything to do with what version of ASP.NET you used. It's more likely your site gained popularity and thus the wrath of the Chinese bots. By the way, `AntiForgeryToken` is used to protect from [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), not bots that call your pages. And adding hidden fields to try and trick them is hardly considered a security measure.

reCAPTCHA is your best bet. Unless it's a Chinese workshop where people are slaving to register accounts, then you have a different problem entirely.

Comment: Thanks. Our website is a product we sell to many users, all installed on their own web servers. I've seen the IIS logs from quite a few users and they are mostly from China. I only mentioned Web Forms vs MVC to illustrate that we never experienced problems previously, so I was wondering if there is something specific in my implementation in MVC that I was doing wrong. To me the logs imply it is more automated than just a human trying it, the requests come in spells just seconds apart, often trying pages that don't exist first.